# Pylint says module cannot be imported

Tags: python, unit-testing, pylint

I have a Python module that performs unit testing on a module I have written. The unit test is placed in a folder called tests, and the module I am testing is one directory above. So, my unit testing file has the following header.

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import table_builder
```

But when I lint this unit test code, I receive the following errors:

```
No config file found, using default configuration
************* Module unittests_table_builder
E:  9, 0: Unable to import 'table_builder' (import-error)
C:  9, 0: Import "import table_builder" should be placed at the top of the           module (wrong-import-position)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 4.55/10 (previous run: 4.55/10, +0.00)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: add ../ to your PYTHONPATH env var before running. get a script to resolve the abs path first. how this is done depends on OS.

Comment: This code will be run by Travis during continuous integration. How do I proceed?

Comment: Never done this, but have you tried this? https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/ set a PYTHONPATH env var.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke the tester from the command line, it will automatically update `sys.path` for you without needing to do it form your test. Using [test discovery](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) mode, it will locate and run all the tests in a directory tree. It's also possible to run individual tests.

```
$ python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "*_test.py"
```

You can also import from a parent module using the [relative import](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) syntax:

```
from .. import my_module
```

Comment: Doesn't look like relative imports are pep8 compliant either.

Comment: I tried the test discovery mode, and it didn't work.